# this row number placeholder excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am writing some formulas for my spreadsheets and wondered if there was a placeholder for this row number.

For example say I am using the formula:

```
=C4+SUM(F4:N4)
```

I know I can autofill this, but what I really want is some stock formula like:

```
=C{this.row}+SUM(F{this.row}:N{this.row})
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function you need is `INDIRECT(CELL/RANGE as string)`

The `INDIRECT` function takes in a string and uses it to evaluate a cell or range location. This is where you get the flexibility (aka indirection) that you need.

eg your formula would be:

```
=INDIRECT("C" & ROW()) + SUM(INDIRECT("F" & ROW() & ":N" & ROW()))
```